# Ionic Native with console log from ionic cordova run ios -c

Tags: ionic-framework, native, console.log

I have searched all over to get this answer but nothing works.
I am building an iPad app in Ionic 2 that uses various native plugins.
I want to be able to test the native features and observe the console logs but nothing gets logged, using either the ios emulator or an iPad device.
Ideally I also want livereload but I'll take what I can get.

I eventually got to display console logs in Xcode but that involves running

```
cordova platform prepare
```

then running the process from Xcode manually every time I make a single edit. This takes much longer than

```
ionic cordova run ios --target="iPad-Air" -c
```

Why can I not just see the logs when I use run?
I have looked at where it says the console.log file is saved to but no file gets created. I created the file myself and gave it full 777 permissions and still nothing.

ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
    Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.2
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
System:
    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v8.8.0
    npm        : 5.4.2
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
Environment Variables:
    ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:
    backend : pro
```

Comment: Do you have cordova-plugin-console in your package.json?

Comment: Yes `cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"`

Comment: Hmm if not that then I would suggest you ask this on the official forum or Slack channel.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone else who has trawled the forums and tried all the solutions where it seems everyone else can console.log except you, I will post what I have discovered. This is not a total solution but may identify the cause for some.

I was specifying the target as iPad-Air. When I didn't, the simulator started in iPhone-6. That is not what I wanted but there in my console was a very welcome console log message.

So I experimented a little and found that iPad-Air 10.0 and iPad-Air-2 10.0 and above will log to the console but 9.3 and lower (Not tested exhaustively) would not.

So for me, this solution will let me continue to develop with livereload and console logs and what's left of my hair.

Hopefully it will save someone else's hair loss too.

FYI you can set your chosen device as a project default in platforms/ios/cordova/lib/run.js in the deployToSim function. There should be a line like `if (emulator.indexOf('iPhone') === 0) {` swap out 'iPhone' (or whatever it is for you) and replace it with 'iPad-Air-2, 10.0' or whatever you need and have available in your simulator list. `ios-sim showdevicetypes`

Good luck!